# Why sketch allow 0.5x export in dropdown?

Tags: export, sketch-app, tools, mac, zoom

Can anyone tell me why Sketch(mac tool for designers) enable us to export half sized of anything?

Why they made it so easy?

Answer (score 1):

Many people design elements, especially mobile interfaces, at twice the size to be able to preview the files at native resolution and then may need to export at 1X for devices with lower resolution. My understanding is that the trend is moving towards designing at 1x, which can more easily be scaled up to 2x, 3x, or 124x ;)